# Secondary menu links

Tags: routes, navigation

I have a main menu with links:
menu1
menu2
menu3
menu4

When entering the menu1 I want to display a secondary menu with links:
sub-menu1
sub-menu2
sub-menu3

and sub-menu1 to be activated as a default.
Every sub-menu has to have a separate page, because in every sub-page the wallpaper will be different.

When entering the sub-menu2, there will be different content, wallpaper, the chosen sub-menu will be activated and also his parent menu, in this case menu1.

How can I do this?

Comment: OK, converted my comment to a bit more elaborated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all you need is normal menu 2 levels deep. Use [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) for greater control what to display where.

Make sub-menu1 and menu1 menu elements to point to the same node to get "sub-menu1 to be activated as a default" requirement.

For a background, just add [background field](https://drupal.org/project/backgroundfield) to your content type, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [menu_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) to override your menu :

try this code in your template.php :

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__MACHINENAME($variables) {
$menuTree = menu_build_tree('MACHINENAME');
$output = '<ul id="nav">';
foreach ($menuTree as $item)
{
    $output .= '<li>' . $hasSub;
    if (count($item['below']) > 0)
    {
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';

        foreach ($item['below'] as $subItem)
        {
          $output .= '<li class = "'.$class.'"><a href="' . url($subItem['link']   
          ['link_path']) . '">' . $subItem['link']['link_title'] . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    $output .= '</li>';
}
$output .= '</ul>';
return $output;
}
```